This is exactly the wrong way to connect this DC circuit breaker, is it not?
This is another little spin-off question of the main one:
DC breakers does polarity really matter? where I want to avoid that it gets flagged as a question that's moving target.
One answer that has since been deleted is showing a picture from the official store of one of those DC breaker manufacturers on AliBaba, in lieu of an actual data sheet.

And I think this is very wrong! I am basing my verdict on this paper: Discussion Paper on the Correct Wiring of Double Pole DC Circuit Breakers .
From this I have concluded that the + and - markings on these breakers are indicative of the source, not the load, and source side and load side can be reversed if +/- is also reversed.
So look at this symbol closely:

It says that if you come with source from above, your plus needs to be on the right, and your minus on the left, and the load side has plus on the right (of course) and minus on the left. And that is exactly opposite to the wiring diagram shown by the manufacturer. But as we all know, we can trust a Chinese product itself more than their documentation that's full of spelling errors and content errors, because it's not the engineers that write or even check this information.
I just want to bounce this off the esteemed colleagues here, and see if at least we can hang our hat on the clear interpretation of these markings. I am actually also doing a full load break test for all my breakers to make sure they don't catch flames in my application when tripped or manually switched. But that is after I made sure I have the connections right.

If you can find the original factory documentation it will typically be much more reliable than whatever fly-by-night sellers on Ali etc. will supply. I rather suspect that 'TOMZN' does not actually manufacture anything and it's having its name stuck on things made by the many real manufacturers of such products such as circuit breakers in China. There is an astounding number of such makers, all producing decent looking products.

+,- polarity depends on intended source or destination like Tx to Rx so be sure you understand which it is. Dont get it wrong

@Burglups where I am, this is all I get. And even on Amazon USA you mostly get that stuff. It is actually quite likely that ABB and Siemens breakers end up Made in China as well. I just have to make do, and so far, my tests have been without incident. I turned off the 7A/130V on a breaker supposedly not bipolar. And I switched off 10A/50V without incident (and that breaker is intentionally installed reverse, because the more likely overload event is when the charge controller shorts out pulling unlimited current from the battery). Now all that remains is a test of 125A/50V to the inverter.

Many reputable brands don't care about polarity. There's a special hell for people who use safety equipment from known trash vendors. Literally, why bother, just use these https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2TJEzdqtXlQ. ......... "it's all made in China" that's an excuse. China doesn't equate to bad.  Shit vendors with no liability equate to bad.

Yes, by my reading (assuming current always flows from "input" to "output") that diagram is exactly wrong.

+,- polarity depends on intended source or destination like Tx to Rx so be sure you understand which it is. Dont get it wrong. I understand it as correct referring to flyback Polarity after open


to - refers to the way current flows + -> -  when it is connected properly. It's that simple. So it would apply to the polarity of the source connections if the load is consuming power.  If the load can back power the source then a polarized breaker can't be (safely) used.


On their partner sites they show how to cascade breakers - to + for each rail to increase Vdc ratings from 250, 600,800,1000 and show Input on top and Load out bottom.  https://generalpower.lk/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/63A-600V-2P-DC-MCB.pdf  "forbid reverse polarity". Again I recognize the markings of x = input break and polarity for voltage , not current but I understand you see it as wrong.
